# Remove extension but preserve parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been wondering, how to remove the extension but preserve the parameters of an url? For example: `search.php?q=test` becomes `/search?q=test`.

I have tried the following, but it removes the entire `search.php` from the url:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} search
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} search
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To remove an extension, you typically check if the requested filename (with extension) exists, and then rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.ext -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.ext [L]
```

---

The rule above is a generic approach, working for any file ending in `.ext`.

If you want to rewrite just one fixed file, you can do so by naming the relevant file explicitly, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^search$ /search.php [L]
```

---

[mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) preserves a query string by default, as long as you don't add your own

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> *By default, the query string is passed through unchanged.* You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

Comment: How can you specify only one file (so in my case search.php) to apply this rule to? Like this? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} search

Comment: What do you mean? This rule works for all files ending in `.ext`.